# Printing from Web-based App in android studio?

Tags: java, android

I've put my web-based application to a WebView in android studio but it does not trigger the printing action from the web and show printing pop up window to print the invoice that I want to print, is there any way to automatically trigger the print action button from the web??

Answer (score 0):

`window.print()` does trigger the printing dialog in most browsers. Not sure if this works from inside a webview though.